# How can I instantiate an object within a static class without creating an instance of the main class in Processing

Tags: java, class, nested, processing, instantiation

I am writing a program in Java (Processing 4).

Processing hides some stuff in the background which makes this more complicated. The main program "GeometryView" extends the PApplet class and has the usual functions. (This is the first tab that is created when creating a project in Processing)

```
ArrayList<Datum> datums = new ArrayList<Datum>();

void setup(){
  size(1400, 900);
  surface.setResizable(true);
  //fullScreen();
  frameRate(120);
  datums.add(new Datum(0,0));
  datums.add(new Datum(1,2));
  datums.add(new Datum(3,4));
}

void draw() {
  background(30);
  stroke(220);
  if(Functions.convex(datums.get(0),datums.get(1),datums.get(2))){
    println("These points are part of a convex corner of geometry");
  }
}
```

I have a class that I use to hold X and Y values named "Datum". This is a separate tab in Processing.

```
class Datum {
  float x;
  float y;
  
  Datum(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void drawDatum(int size){
    //print("X = " + this.x + ", Y = " + this.y);
    ellipse(this.x, -this.y, size, size);
  }
  
  Datum clone(){
    return new Datum(x,y);
  }
  
}
```

Under a separate tab "Functions", I have a static class I use to hold different functions. This is to simplify the main parts of the program because I can call these functions without having to instantiate the class. (This may not be the correct way to do this, but it works for now. I just have to call "Functions.funcName();" This may also be a clue as to what my issue is)

```
static class Functions{
 //...
 //other functions
 //...

  static float crossproduct(Datum a, Datum b) {
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
  }

  static boolean convex(Datum a, Datum b, Datum c) {
    Datum ab = new Datum(b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y); // Error here on "new Datum(x,y)"
    Datum bc = new Datum(c.x - b.x, c.y - b.y);
  
    return crossproduct(ab, bc) > 0;
  }
}
```

On the line with

```
Datum ab = new Datum(b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y);
```

I am getting an error that says

> "No enclosing instance of type GeometryView is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type GeometryView." (GeometryView is the name of the main class and project).

I read some other posts that mentioned making the Datum class static, but then I can't access the built-in Processing functions like ellipse() and I get this error.

> "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method ellipse(float, float, float, float) from the type PApplet"

```
void drawDatum(int size){
    //print("X = " + this.x + ", Y = " + this.y);
    ellipse(this.x, -this.y, size, size); // <---- Error is here
  }
```

Another solution was to create another instance of the main class to access the Datum class. Maybe that would work, but seems like it could be a performance issue to instantiate the entire program again just to access a simple class.

How can I use "new Datum(x,y)" inside my Functions class without breaking other parts of my program? Will creating a reference to my main class potentially cause memory issues or is it just creating a reference?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that is consistent with the question you're asking. Static classes can only exist nested in other classes, yet the `Functions` class you show is not nested in another class. Also the error you show and the code you mention call an `ellipse` method, yet none of the code you show _defines_ that method.

Comment: Also, how is the title relevant to your question?

Comment: The ellipse method is part of Processings API. I believe every class in Processing is inside the PApplet class but I haven’t been able to find clear info about this. Also the title got messed up somehow. That’s NOT what the title was when I reviewed my question

Comment: I believe the Functions class inherits from the PApplet class. Processing tries to make things simple for you, but sometimes makes it more complicated because it hides how the classes are structured

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I spent an hour trying to figure out how to word my question in a way that makes sense, leaving every bit of code you'd need to figure out the problem without making it complicated. I also searched Google for the answer for over two hours today and I explained what I found and why the answers in those posts did not answer my question. I can add more to this if you like but I thought it would only make it more complicated

Comment: the `Datum` class must be `static`; the `drawDatum` method moved (and adapted) to somewhere else, e.g. main program - Otherwise the *functions* must receive an additional parameter: a `Supplier` or similar that can create a `Datum` || thinking a bit more, why not have the functions on `Datum` itself? (*kind of inconsistent* to have `drawDatum` on it, but other operation somewhere else)

Comment: @user85421 I just added a method inside the Datum class that returns a new Datum. I may not do everything correctly, but I try my best to learn and improve. I watch the Coding Train on youtube and he always adds a `show()` method inside classes so he can easily just call the method and the drawing is done behind the scenes.

Comment: but I would still prefer having `crossProduct` and similar declared on `Datum` itself... I also do not like a data class like `Datum` knowing about the main program; maybe change the draw method to receive the `GeometryView` instance (like is done with Java Swing) || (( and I do not thrust most **video** tutorials about programing ))

Comment: @user85421 Thanks! I will implement that. Not sure why I didn't think about that.

Comment: @user85421 I'm willing to learn whatever I can. How would I keep the data class separate? what implications does it have to leave it the way it is? What is the data type of the `GeometryView` instance for passing it into my method?

Comment: sorry, I do not know Processing - I am here only because the question is marked with the [tag:java] tag. I thought, from your question, that `GeometryView` is the (type of) the main program... but if it "extends the PApplet", maybe you can use `PApplet` (if it has the drawing methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `expressionOfTypeGeometryView.new Datum()` to get rid of that error, but opens a new question: How do you get *that*. Well, Datum instances have such a reference - non-static inner classes have a secret hidden field of its outer type (and there IS an outer type here, but processing is hiding, that too - there's a lot of voodoo magic going on here which makes this unfortunately a bit complicated).

To end up with code that isn't an utter disaster to read, though, I suggest this alternative take. Add to your Datum class:

```
public Datum newDatum(int x, int y) {
  return new Datum(x, y);
}
```

This does work because Datum does have that hidden field - it can therefore make new Datum objects 'out of the box' without needing the weird `expr.new Datum` syntax. It means you need an instance of Datum to make new Datum objects - but you do have an instance.

Alternatively, for even nicer API, try:

```
public Datum subtract(Datum other) {
  return new Datum(x - other.x, y - other.y);
}
```

and replace `Datum ab = new Datum(b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y);` in your code with `Datum ab = b.subtract(a);` which strikes me as just more readable in general - the code now describes intent better.

Comment: Perfect answer! I do have one more question. another part of my code needs something similar. I created a reference using:  `GeometryView gv = new GeometryView();` Does that create a copy of my program in memory or just a reference to it?

Comment: You don't want a _new_ view. `new`, as the word suggests, always creates a new reference. That's not a full copy, (only a block of memory to contain the values of the fields, you don't make copies of code with that, that'd be pointless, think about it) but, still not what you want (it gets a fresh version of all fields). `GeometryView gv = new GeometryView()` just isn't the answer. Each non-static class has a GV ref (`GeometryView gv = GeometryView.this;` will get you that in a variable you can then pass around).